# map() into an argument that is not the first argument

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a function that takes multiple arguments (simple reproducible example below):

```
return_numbers <- function(first = 1, last = 10){
  seq(first, last)
}
```

If I then have a vector that I want to `map()`, for example:

```
x <- c(5, 6, 7)
```

It's quite easy to `map()` the vector `x` into the first argument of the function:

```
map(x, return_numbers)

[[1]]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9  10

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9  10

[[3]]
[1]  7  8  9  10
```

But I can't work out how to map `x` into the second argument `(last = )`.

I referred to Hadley Wickham's Advanced R:
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#change-argument

and tried this, but I must be doing something wrong:

```
map(x, ~ return_numbers(x, last = .x))
```

My desired output would be:

```
[[1]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 

[[2]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  

[[3]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
map(x, ~return_numbers(last = .))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also mention the first argument explicitly :

```r
return_numbers <- function(first = 1, last = 10){
  seq(first, last)
}
x <- c(5, 6, 7)
purrr::map(x, return_numbers, first=1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>